# Reduce call stacks size in Javascript

Tags: node.js, performance, callstack

When I know that particular call is last in a function and I have to return nothing from the function, Can I reduce call stack size?

Here is the example

```
constructor(){
    this.processNext = this.a;
}

parse(stream){
    stream.on('data', data => {
        this.start(data);
    })
}

start(data){
    this.data += data;
    //somecode
    this.processNext();
}

a(){
    for(; this.index < this.data.length; this.index++){
        //some code
        if(someCondition) {
            this.processThisNext(this.b);
            break;
        }else if(another condition){
            this.processThisNext(this.c);
            break;
        }
    }
}

b(){
    for(; this.index < this.data.length; this.index++){
        //some code
        if(someCondition) {
            this.processThisNext(this.a);
            break;
        }
    }
}

processThisNext(method){
  this.processNext = method;
  this.processNext();
}
c(){}
```

Explanation:

I have divided the code in multiple functions to reduce number of comparisons and to keep it understandable. I'm listening to `data` event of an input stream. `processNext` is a proxy function which is always called when `data` event is triggered. The value of `processNext` keep  changing in the logic.

Now as you can see in above code, when I call `processThisNext`, I actually want to exist from the current function call. At this point, I don't need this and parent function to be present in call stack.

Is there any way I can simplify it? or reduce call stack by some other way?

Answer (score 0):

To exit from the current call stack, one option is to call the next method after a `Promise.resolve` - it'll run as a microtask, after other synchronous Javascript processing is finished:

```
a(){
    for(; this.index < this.data.length; this.index++){
        //some code
        if(someCondition) {
            Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                this.processThisNext(this.b);
            });
            break;
        }else if(another condition){
            Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                this.processThisNext(this.c);
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}

b(){
    for(; this.index < this.data.length; this.index++){
        //some code
        if(someCondition) {
            Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                this.processThisNext(this.a);
            });
            break;
        }
    }
}
```